# How to calculate Big O time complexity for while loops

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, big-o

I am having trouble understanding how while loops affect the Big O time complexity.

For example, how would I calculate the time complexity for the code below?
Since it has a for loop that traverses through each element in the array and two nested while loops my initial thought was O(n^3) for the time complexity but I do not think that is right.

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> ht = new HashMap<>();

for(int j : array){
      if(ht.get(j)) continue;

      int left = j-1;
      //check if hashtable contains number
      while(ht.containsKey(left)){
        //do something
        left--;
      }

      int right = j+1;
      //check if hashtable contains number
      while(ht.containsKey(right)){
        //do something
        right++;
      }

      int diff = right - left;
      if(max < diff) {
        //do something
      }
}
```

Comment: `O(n^3)` would be applicable if you have three nested loops. You only have two levels of nesting, as the inner loops are side-by-side, not nested.

Comment: It looks to me that we don't  have enough information to evaluate either of the two `while` loops. There must be some something that constrains how far `right` and `left` can go, but we don't know what. For all I know, there  is a bug, and one or both of the `while` loops are infinite loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is best case, average case, and worst case.

I'm going to have to assume there is something that constrains the two `while` loops so that neither iterates more than `n` times, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

In the best case, you have O(n).  That is because `if(ht.get(j))` is always `true`, the `continue` path  is always taken. Neither `while` loop is executed.

For the worst case, `if(ht.get(j))` is always `false`,  the `while` loops will be executed. Also, in the worst case, each `while` loop will have `n` passes. [1] The net result is 2 * n for both inner loops multiplied by n for the outer loop:  **(2 * n) * n**. That would give you time complexity of O(n^2). [2]

The lookup time could potentially be a factor. A hash table lookup usually runs in constant time: O(1). That's the best case.  But, the worst case is O(n). This happens when all entries have the same hash code. If that happens, it could potentially change your worst case to O(n^3).

[1] I suspect the worst case, the number of passes of the first `while` loop plus the number  of passes of the second `while` loop  is actually `n` or close to it. But, that doesn't change the result.

[2] In Big O, we chose the term that grows the fastest, and ignore the coefficients. So, in this example, we drop the `2` in `2*n*n`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are `m` and `n` entries in your `HashMap` and `array`, respectively.

Since you have `n` elements for the `for` loop, the complexity can be written as `n * complexity_inside_for`.

Inside the `for` loop, you have two consecutive (not nested) `while` loops, each contributing a complexity of `m` as in worst case it'll need to go through all entries in your `HashMap`. Therefore, `complexity_inside_for = m + m = 2m`.

So overall, time complexity is `n * 2m`. However, as `m` and `n` approach infinity, the number `2` doesn't matter because it is not a function of `m` and/or `n` and can be discarded. This gives a big-O time complexity of `O(m*n)`

Answer (score 0):

for one nested loop the time complexity works like this:  O(n^2).

In each iteration of i, inner loop is executed 'n' times. The time complexity of a loop is equal to the number of times the innermost statement is to be executed.

so for your case that would be O(n^2)+O(n).

there you can find more explanation

[Time-complexity](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/time-complexity)